# Updating User Meta using Theme My Login with Custom Fields

Tags: user-registration, code

I am trying to create a better login and registration form on wordpress. I have installed TML by Jeff and it works wonderfully. However, I am trying to further extend the registration form. I have added both "first_name" and "last_name" as displayed by wordpress but for some reason it seems as though the update_user_meta is not saving whatsoever.

Here's is the code I am using for the two [fields Fname and Lname](http://docs.thememylogin.com/adding-extra-registration-fields/)

```
    <div class="tml-user-first-last-name-wrap" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">
        <span style="width:50%; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 1px; float:left;"><input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" id="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'first_name' ); ?>" size="20" />
        <label for="first_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( '', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    </span>
        <span style="width:50%; padding-left: 1px; padding-right: 25px; float:right;"><input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'last_name' ); ?>" size="20"  />
        <label for="last_name<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( '', 'theme-my-login' ) ?></label>
    </span>
    <br>
    </div>
```

In addition to that I had to add this file into wp-content/plugins/theme-my-login-custom.php

```
    function tml_registration_errors( $errors ) {
if ( empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
    $errors->add( 'empty_first_name', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your first name.' );
if ( empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) )
    $errors->add( 'empty_last_name', '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please enter your last name.' );
return $errors;
    }
    add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'tml_registration_errors' );

    function tml_user_register( $user_id ) {
if ( !empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name'] );
if ( !empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) )
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', $_POST['last_name'] );
   }
    add_action( 'user_register', 'tml_user_register' );
```

In addition to this I also attempted the wordpress default form available [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Registration_Form).

I'm at a loss because I'm not sure what I've done wrong.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Good news is its not the memberships plugin
Bad news is it is W3 Total Cache.
I have forced the site not to cache the register page but it still seems to not work.

Update: I know what it is: I forgot to tell w3tc to not cache: theme-my-login-custom.php